# Node.js: Infinite loop fails with no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand why this code in nodejs throwing **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error

```
function infinite(i) {
    i++;
    infinite(i);
}
infinite(0);
```

But when i add console.log(i); to the function like this

```
function infinite(i) {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    infinite(i);
}
infinite(0);
```

The execution fails after a while without any errors, So my question here what is the difference ? in both cases the function is called recursively so its supposed to cause a **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

does this kind of output blocking because i used `console.log()` so the node couldn't print the error ?

Comment: I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` on the second code sample as well (after printing a lot to the console).

Comment: I got the same error in both cases.

Comment: Yes, maybe there's a problem with flushing the standard output.

Comment: i am keep trying but in second code it keep counting to 13996 then the execution just fails without any errors, maybe its something related to my hardware or maybe the operating system ? i am trying on windows OS using the CMD and the powershell and i get same result in both with no errors